# ASN.1 Unmarshalling using go structs gives tags don't match error

Tags: go, asn.1

I am trying to do ASN.1 marshal/unmarshal for the following definition:

```
ACEI    ::= SEQUENCE {
message         MessageFields,
neRegNumber     OCTET STRING OPTIONAL,
gpsInfo         GpsInfo OPTIONAL,
siteInfo        OCTET STRING OPTIONAL,
nlementID   INTEGER(0..16777216) OPTIONAL,
...
}

GpsInfo         ::= SEQUENCE {
gpsLat      INTEGER(-900000000..900000000) OPTIONAL,
gpsLong     INTEGER(-1800000000..1800000000) OPTIONAL,
gpsAlt      INTEGER OPTIONAL,
...
}
MessageFields       ::= SEQUENCE {
messageSequence     INTEGER (1..65535),
bsId    INTEGER (1..65535) OPTIONAL,
neID        INTEGER(0..16777216) OPTIONAL, -- unsigned int
nelementID  INTEGER(0..16777216) OPTIONAL, -- unsigned int
...
}
```

The corresponding go structs are:

```
type ACEI struct {
    Message          MessageFields
    NeRegNumber      []byte `asn1:"optional"`
    GPSInfo          GPSInfo `asn1:"optional"`
    SiteInfo         []byte `asn1:"optional"`
    NElementID       int `asn1:"optional"`
}

type GPSInfo struct {
    GpsLatitude  int `asn1:"optional"`
    GpsLongitude int `asn1:"optional"`
    GpsAltitude  int `asn1:"optional"`
}

type MessageFields struct {
    MessageSequence  int
    BsId             int `asn1:"optional"`
    NeID             int `asn1:"optional"`
    NElementID       int `asn1:"optional"`
}
```

I am filling in the structs, marshalling them and then converting them to hex.
When I do that, the hex sequence (seqA) obtained is:

> 302e300f020101020204d2020215b302021a0a040430413042300b02019c020200be020200c80404304330440202309c

When I do the same on http://asn1-playground.oss.com/, I get the following hex sequence (seqB):

> 302AA00F 80010181 0204D282 0215B383 021A0A81 020A0BA2 0B80019C 810200BE
>   820200C8 83020C0D 8402309C

I fed in both these hex sequences to the unmarshal function; while the seqA is correctly unmarshalled, unmarshalling seqB gives me the following error:

> Error while unmarshalling:  asn1: structure error: tags don't match (16 vs {class:2 tag:0 length:15 isCompound:true}) {optional:false explicit:false application:false defaultValue: tag: stringType:0 timeType:0 set:false omitEmpty:false} MessageFields @2

This is the code that marshals/unmarshals:

```
func main() {
    //Marshalling
    messageSequence := structs.MessageFields{1, 1234, 5555, 6666}
    gpsInfo := structs.GPSInfo{-100, 190, 200}
    val := structs.ACEI{messageSequence, []byte("0A0B"), gpsInfo, []byte("0C0D"), 12444}
    hexmdata := asn1Marshal(val)

    //Unmarshalling hex sequence (seqA) generated by go code
    res1, _ := asn1Unmarshal(hexmdata)
    fmt.Println(res1)

    //Unmarshalling hex sequence (seqB) generated by http://asn1-playground.oss.com/ 
    res2, _ := asn1Unmarshal(strings.ToLower("302AA00F800101810204D2820215B383021A0A81020A0BA20B80019C810200BE820200C883020C0D8402309C"))
    fmt.Println(res2)
}

func asn1Unmarshal(hexmdata string) (structs.ACEI, error){
    fmt.Println(hexmdata)
    s, _ := hex.DecodeString(hexmdata)
    res := structs.ACEI{}
    _, err := asn1.Unmarshal(s, &res)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error while unmarshalling: ", err)
    }
    return res, err
}

func asn1Marshal(data structs.ACEI) string {
    mdata, _ := asn1.Marshal(data)
    hexmdata := hex.EncodeToString(mdata)
    return hexmdata
}
```

1. Why are the hex sequences different for the same definition?
2. How can I correct the error that I get during unmarshalling of seqB?

EDIT: Conversely, the go code sequence (seqA) when fed to http://asn1-playground.oss.com/ gives me this error:

```
ACEI SEQUENCE: tag = [UNIVERSAL 16] constructed; length = 46
D0033E: Tag mismatch or tag not expected: [UNIVERSAL 16] (expected tag [0]); check field 'message' (type: MessageFields) of PDU #1 'ACEI'.
  *SKIPPED*: tag = [UNIVERSAL 16] constructed; length = 15
    <skipped>
D0033E: Tag mismatch or tag not expected: [UNIVERSAL 4] (expected tag [0]); check field 'message' (type: MessageFields) of PDU #1 'ACEI'.
  *SKIPPED*: tag = [UNIVERSAL 4] primitive; length = 4
    <skipped>
D0033E: Tag mismatch or tag not expected: [UNIVERSAL 16] (expected tag [0]); check field 'message' (type: MessageFields) of PDU #1 'ACEI'.
  *SKIPPED*: tag = [UNIVERSAL 16] constructed; length = 11
    <skipped>
D0033E: Tag mismatch or tag not expected: [UNIVERSAL 4] (expected tag [0]); check field 'message' (type: MessageFields) of PDU #1 'ACEI'.
  *SKIPPED*: tag = [UNIVERSAL 4] primitive; length = 4
    <skipped>
D0033E: Tag mismatch or tag not expected: [UNIVERSAL 2] (expected tag [0]); check field 'message' (type: MessageFields) of PDU #1 'ACEI'.
  *SKIPPED*: tag = [UNIVERSAL 2] primitive; length = 2
    <skipped>
D0049E: Field omitted: "message"; check PDU #1 'ACEI'.
S0012E: Decoding of PDU #1 failed with the return code '5'.
```

EDIT 2: After editing the structs according to @YaFred's suggestion, my structs look like this now:

```
type ACEI struct {
        Message          MessageFields `asn1:"application,tag:0,implicit"`
        NeRegNumber      []byte `asn1:"application,tag:1,implicit,optional"`
        GPSInfo          GPSInfo `asn1:"application,tag:2,implicit,optional"`
        SiteInfo         []byte `asn1:"application,tag:3,implicit,optional"`
        NElementID int `asn1:"application,tag:4,implicit,optional"`
    }

type GPSInfo struct {
    GpsLatitude  int `asn1:"application,tag:0,implicit,optional"`
    GpsLongitude int `asn1:"application,tag:1,implicit,optional"`
    GpsAltitude int `asn1:"application,tag:2,implicit,optional"`
}

type MessageFields struct {
    MessageSequence  int `asn1:"application,tag:0,implicit"`
    BsId int `asn1:"application,tag:1,implicit,optional"`
    NeID        int `asn1:"application,tag:2,implicit,optional"`
    NElementID int `asn1:"application,tag:3,implicit,optional"`
}
```

Marshalling using these structs gives me the same hex code as that obtained from asn playground. But, the unmarshalling fails with the following error:

> Hex code:
>   302aa00f800101810204d2820215b383021a0a81020a0ba20b80019c810200be820200c883020c0d8402309c

Error (the same error I was getting before when I tried to unmarshall hex code (from asn playground) using go code):

> Error while unmarshalling:  asn1: structure error: tags don't match (0
>   vs {class:2 tag:0 length:15 isCompound:true}) {optional:false
>   explicit:false application:true defaultValue: tag:0xc042008348
>   stringType:0 timeType:0 set:false omitEmpty:false} MessageFields @2

EDIT 3: Removing the "application" tag from the structs helps me unmarshal the hex code as expected.

Comment: It seems to me that the `asn1Marshal` GO function is not correctly computing the tags for the elements in your structures for some reason. You should make sure that your module declaration has the automatic tags, i.e. it should look something like this `ModuleName DEFINITIONS AUTOMATIC TAGS ::= BEGIN`.

Comment: Thanks! Should I include the automatic tags in my go structs? If yes, how can that be done?

Comment: You should also double check with the reference material that AUTOMATIC tagging is what you want.  asn1-playground defaults to it, but IMPLICIT (or EXPLICIT) is frequently seen more in the wild.

Comment: The tag is similar to the one mentioned in the first comment: "ModuleName DEFINITIONS AUTOMATIC TAGS..." I don't understand how this tag should be included in the go code.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not familiar with the GO ASN.1 tools. Form what I see in your ASN.1 schema and the generated encoding, there seems to be some kind of problem with the GO implementation of ASN.1 tools. Considering the fact that you do not have manual tags in the types definition and that you have OPTIONAL fields with the same type, the only way to compile this schema is to use AUTOMATIC TAGS (the asn1 playground will issue schema compiling errors when not using AUTOMATIC TAGS). But looking at your seqA encoding it seems that for some unknown reason the GO tools use IMPLICIT tags.

Comment: This is the bytes that I get when I marshall using go code: [48 46 48 15 2 1 1 2 2 4 210 2 2 21 179 2 2 26 10 4 4 48 65 48 66 48 11 2 1 156 2 2 0 190 2 2 0 200 4 4 48 67 48 68 2 2 48 156] 
If the first value represents tag, why is it 48? Shouldn't it be 16 since I am encoding a Sequence?

Comment: @Aarvi The encoding of tags also includes some additional information, i.e. if the inner data is a primitive or constructed types, and this is encoded as a single bit in the 3 bit of the byte. In the case of SEQUENCE type, the tag will also have the third bit set and as a result instead of 16 you end up with 48.

Comment: @Andrei Bozantan, thanks for the clarification! One more observation: The length is 42 bytes in case of the playground, and the length is 46 for go code. Any idea why there is a disparity in the lengths?

Comment: @Aarvi regarding the difference in lengths, this is cause by differences in how the OCTET STRING values are parsed: the `asn1Marshal` GO function actually encodes the ASCII codes of the characters from the strings (it considers that the OCTET STRING values are composed of 4 bytes); the OSS playground considers that the values for the OCTET STRING are actually hex encodings (the values are composed of 2 bytes). You can easily verify this by using this tool http://lapo.it/asn1js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where you input your types (with your tool as well as with http://asn1-playground.oss.com/), **you must use a module**. If not, it is not a valid asn1 specification (and your tool as well as oss.com should reject it).

```
My-module DEFINITIONS ::= 
BEGIN 

ACEI    ::= SEQUENCE {
etc ...

END
```

The fact that tools accept to encode types without knowing the module tagging context is the reason for many questions on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asn.1

To answer the second question (about the difference of length), you should show what values you gave to oss.com .. it's likely:

```
neRegNumber  '0A0B'H
siteInfo     '0C0D'H
```

They are both 2 bytes long

But when you write `[]byte("0A0B")` you are certainly asking Go to give you the bytes of the string "0A0B" (indeed 30 41 30 42 in ASCII)

I think `[]byte{10,11}` should give you the bytes for `'0A0B'H`

EDITED

If your tool does not take an asn.1 module, you can still do the automatic tagging yourself

```
ACEI    ::= SEQUENCE {
message         [0] IMPLICIT MessageFields,
neRegNumber     [1] IMPLICIT OCTET STRING OPTIONAL,
gpsInfo         [2] IMPLICIT GpsInfo OPTIONAL,
siteInfo        [3] IMPLICIT OCTET STRING OPTIONAL,
nlementID       [4] IMPLICIT INTEGER(0..16777216) OPTIONAL,
...
}

GpsInfo         ::= SEQUENCE {
gpsLat      [0] IMPLICIT INTEGER(-900000000..900000000) OPTIONAL,
gpsLong     [1] IMPLICIT INTEGER(-1800000000..1800000000) OPTIONAL,
gpsAlt      [2] IMPLICIT INTEGER OPTIONAL,
...
}
MessageFields       ::= SEQUENCE {
messageSequence     [0] IMPLICIT INTEGER (1..65535),
bsId                [1] IMPLICIT INTEGER (1..65535) OPTIONAL,
neID                [2] IMPLICIT INTEGER(0..16777216) OPTIONAL, -- unsigned int
nelementID          [3] IMPLICIT INTEGER(0..16777216) OPTIONAL, -- unsigned int
...
}
```

EDITED 2 (based on chat with @Aarvi)

It just occurred to me that https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/asn1/ does not involve an ASN.1 compiler.

Instead a Go struct is manually written and annotated.

So following ASN.1 type (in a module with AUTOMATICS TAGS selected)

```
GpsInfo         ::= SEQUENCE {
   gpsLat      INTEGER(-900000000..900000000) OPTIONAL,
   gpsLong     INTEGER(-1800000000..1800000000) OPTIONAL,
   gpsAlt      INTEGER OPTIONAL,
   ...
}
```

has to be written manually like this

```
type GPSInfo struct {
    GpsLatitude  int `asn1:"tag:0,implicit,optional"`
    GpsLongitude int `asn1:"tag:1,implicit,optional"`
    GpsAltitude int `asn1:"tag:2,implicit,optional"`
}
```

Comment: Any idea how to do the module tagging in Go? The ASN definition file I have has a definition like "Module-name DEFINITIONS AUTOMATIC TAGS ::="

Comment: Yeah, I am using the same.

Comment: As far I see the implementation is extremely limited. Can you use my suggestions in the edited answer ?

Comment: I tried your suggestion, and I have edited my question to include the results of the same. 
PS: There seems to be some bug on SO, the UI looks different to me, and I am not able to edit it as well as I want to. Please bear with me.

Comment: i think you're nearly there. You are mixing text and hexa again. You must provide bytes when unmarshalling. Have a look at https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/hex/#DecodeString

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169126/discussion-between-aarvi-and-yafred).